# Open New Instance of Excel 2010 with every file

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am using Excel 2010 and want to manage a large Excel files.

So I would like to open a new Excel Instance when opening every file from my Windows Explorer. At the point all files are opened in the same Excel Instance.

Any assistance is kindly appreciated.

John.

[
I fould this:
http://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/how-to-open-a-new-instance-of-excel-2007-workbooks/
]

Comment: Belongs in superuser.SE

Comment: See solution here: http://dottech.org/26491/how-to-force-microsoft-excel-to-open-files-in-new-window-how-to-guide/

Comment: link to superuser site that answer this question http://superuser.com/questions/21602/open-excel-files-in-new-window/894941#894941

Answer (score 10):

Go to a folder in Windows Explorer, then **Tools** -> **Folder Options**, then the **File Types** tab. For each of XLSM, XLSB, XLSX, etcetera, select it, then click **Advanced**, select **Open** in the Actions list, then click **Edit**.

Adjust the settings to:

**Application used to perform action:** - "C:...\EXCEL.EXE" "%1"

**Use DDE** - Checked

**DDE Message *LEAVE BLANK***

**Application** - Excel

**Topic** - System

Comment: Ah... just re-read your question and realised that you are using Excel 2010, this certainly works for 2007. Haven't deleted the post in case it works for 2010 also...

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/21602/open-excel-files-in-new-window

Comment: How would one do this in windows vista/7 - there is no "File types" tab anymore, I don't see any "advanced/edit" options under the "Default programs" in the control panel (which I think is the closest thing functionality wise) - the closest I see is [this](http://dottech.org/26491/how-to-force-microsoft-excel-to-open-files-in-new-window-how-to-guide/) which works, but is a complete PITA.

Comment: If you do this, you won't be able to use the full features of copy & paste between Excel instances. I.e. if you copy cells with formulas, the formulas will be converted to values.

Answer (score 2):

You need to launch excel and then load the file, so it will be in another instance.

Comment: I do not have 2010 at the moment, but have you tried this? I ask, because I seem to remember that you end up with one instance when using 2010 as seen in task manager.

Comment: I found the following: http://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/how-to-open-a-new-instance-of-excel-2007-workbooks/