# Move worksheet to a new window

Tags: excel, excel-2010, multiple-monitors

I was wondering if it is possible to avoid the general behavior of MS Excel 2010 when opening a new document while one instance of the program is already running. Basically what happens is that the program opens the new spreadsheet in the current environment, as a new workbook.

What I would like to do is to set as default (or find an easy and quick way to do it with a keyboard short-cut / Macro) the opening of the a new workbook in a new instance of MS Excel.

The final goal is to allow me to keep one workbook in one monitor and move the second one in a second monitor (I'm working with 2 monitors at work).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to open the workbook in separate instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957334/trying-to-open-the-workbook-in-separate-instance)

Comment: @mehow I highly doubt that is a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open New Instance of Excel 2010 with every file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691054/open-new-instance-of-excel-2010-with-every-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

If you want to do this in VBA code, then you can use the following:

```
Sub OpenInNewInstance()
    Dim xlApp As Application
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    xlApp.Visible = True
End Sub
```

---

For a none VBA solution you can open up two instances of excel and open a document from the file menu in each instance.

There is this method I found on SuperUser for opening all sheets in new instances of Excel

```
In Excel 2003, go to Tools -> Options -> General tab.

Make sure the option, ‘Ignore other applications’ is checked.

In Excel 2007 & 2010, Click the Office button -> Excel Options -> Advanced.

Under General, check ‘Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange’.
```

https://superuser.com/questions/21602/open-excel-files-in-new-window

---

Or you can make a registry edit (probably want to back up first)

```
strart - run - regedit:

Left column

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Excel.Sheet.8/shell/Open/commend:

Right column {adding (space)"%1"}

Double Click on (Default) and write - "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE" /e "%1"

Right Click on Command – choose "rename" and add something to the name  - for example 2 (commend2).

Left column

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Excel.Sheet.8/shell/Open/ddeexec:

Right Click on the folder ddeexec and choose "rename" and add something to the name  - for example 2 (ddeexec2)

Left column

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Excel.Sheet.12/shell/Open/commend:

Right column {adding (space)"%1"}

Double Click on (Default) and write - "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE" /e "%1"

Right Click on Command – choose "rename" and add something to the name  - for example 2 (commend2).
```

Also depending on what version of Excel you are using there may be an option in the `View` Menu to open a new Window.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/i-want-to-open-2-excel-files-in-separate-windows/f7588d9a-3c41-466f-8f01-3b6ab9661ae3)

Comment: Do you know any other way to do it without editing the registry key? Unfortunately is not my personal computer.

Comment: You could try http://superuser.com/questions/21602/open-excel-files-in-new-window

Comment: I've realised the answer on Superuser cause an error message when you exit the current instance of Excel and try to open a new one. It is reported on the comments following the answer in Superuser too. That's a shame. I will give a go to the VBA script.